# Join two tables with not repeating values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables 
TableA

```
id    name
1     asd
2     afg
3     qwe
4     dsf
```

TableB

```
id    desc    uni
1     kfgh    asad
1     oiuy    asad
1     wert    asad
3     wewe    sfds
4     lkjh    qwer
4     poiu    qwer
```

now i want join both these tables
to get values in column `uni` when i tried inner join

```
SELECT     uni FROM      tableA as A JOIN tableB as B  ON  A.id = B.id
```

it gives me all rows in TableB.as you noticed row with id 1 three times.And I can't use distinct here as this is a small part of a large query and this join statement will affect whole query.Can any one tell me what kind of join that I need to try.

Comment: Is the content of the field "uni" directly dependend on the field "id"? If yes, you might want to consider moving that relationship into its own table.

Comment: Can't you just use distinct in a sub-query?

Comment: @HaukeP. fild "uni" is directly depended on field "id".But I don't understood your suggestion.Please add it as an anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a sub query to get the distinct bits you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, uni FROM tableb
```

so

```
SELECT     
  uni 
FROM
   tableA as A 
JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT id, uni FROM tableb
     ) as B  
ON  A.id = B.id
```

**EDIT**
if you want all rows from tableA - you need to use a left join

```
SELECT     
  a.id, 
  b.uni 
FROM
   tableA as A 
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT id, uni FROM tableb
     ) as B  
ON  A.id = B.id
```

Comment: your query works fine, except it does not returns row with id=2.
as this is a part of large query I can't leave this row here

Comment: please amend your question to show what output you expect - I don't see a uni corresponding to id=2

Answer (score 0):

Your tables do not seem to be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In particular, they seem to violate the [second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

To fix that, you should change your table structure into something like the following:

**TableA**

```
id    name
1     asd
2     afg
3     qwe
4     dsf
```

**Table Unis**

```
id    uni
1     asad
3     sfds
4     qwer
```

**Table Descs**

```
id    desc
1     kfgh
1     oiuy
1     wert
3     wewe
4     lkjh
4     poiu
```

And use this query:

```
SELECT unis.uni FROM tableA AS A JOIN tableUnis AS unis ON A.id = unis.id
```

Comment: I agree with you on normalization